# I have an arrayList outside of an onClick method that refers to the arrayList, but it is giving me errors

Tags: java, android

I have an arrayList outside of an `onClick()` method. I am referring to some elements in the arrayList in my `onClick()` class. But when I type the name of the `ArrayList` and the list, it highlights in red. Both of the classes are public though.

I have tried putting the code of the arryalist and the list randomization process, but the it re randomizes every time I click something.

The part that is giving me errors is in the first case in the switch case statement, where I try to get the first position in the allImages arraylist, and the first position in the imageList List. They are in the onclick class. The arrayList and List are outside of that class.

I cannot put the arrayList and List inside of the class, because that will re randomize every time I click something. (I am trying to make a matching game)

Here is the code:

```
public void Random() {

    Integer[] allImages = { R.drawable.cheetah, R.drawable.cheetah, R.drawable.chick, R.drawable.chick, R.drawable.fox,
            R.drawable.fox, R.drawable.giraffe, R.drawable.giraffe, R.drawable.owl,
            R.drawable.owl, R.drawable.panda, R.drawable.panda, R.drawable.sheep, R.drawable.sheep, R.drawable.tiger,
            R.drawable.tiger};
    List<Integer> imageList = Arrays.asList(allImages);
    Collections.shuffle(imageList);
    imageList.toArray(allImages);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    final int id = v.getId();
    if (maxCounter < 2) {
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.one:
                one.setBackgroundResource(allImages[0]); THE ALL IMAGES PART HIGHLIGHTS IN RED
                unmatchedImages[maxCounter] = R.id.one;
                unmatchedImages[maxCounter++] = imageList.get(0); ALSO IMAGE LIST HIGHLIGHTS IN RED 
                break;
            //After this, i have cases for each button
        }
    }
    else {
        one.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.qmarks);
        //After this, i have a setBackgroundResource for each button

    }
}
```

Please help. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please specify exactly which variables you're referring to.

Comment: Add your layout file (xml) and stacktrace/exception (if appears). Correct the description of your problem because it is hard to understand what is not working.

Comment: Sorry, I will fix that. This is the first question I have posted

Answer (score 1):

Is your `Random()` should be method or class?

Base on name, which starts from uppercase (`Random`) it look like class.
But you added `public void` before name, so it's method.

I think you can move your `Random()` method (!) content to your `Activity`. Are you planning to set in `Fragment` or `Activity`?

Steps to do:

1) Move your list as field in your Activity (or fragment - I don't know what you have)

2) Shuffle list in `onCreate()` (or in different place but **before** first usage)

```
// 0 - Use it in your class.
//     This "MainActivity" is only for example - use your name!
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // 1 - List of items
    List<Integer> allImages = {R.drawable.cheetah, R.drawable.cheetah, R.drawable.chick,
            R.drawable.chick, R.drawable.fox, R.drawable.fox, R.drawable.giraffe,
            R.drawable.giraffe, R.drawable.owl, R.drawable.owl, R.drawable.panda,
            R.drawable.panda, R.drawable.sheep, R.drawable.sheep, R.drawable.tiger,
            R.drawable.tiger};

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // 2 - Shuffle them
        Collections.shuffle(imageList);
    }


    .
    .
    .


}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem I see is that yes `Random` is `public` but in the `OnClick()` method your are trying to access a property of `Random` without telling who is the parent.

So instead of just using `allImages` and `imageList.get()` use `Random().allImages` and `Random().imageList.get()` Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Ac2442 ! Thank you so much for trying to help me out. I really appreciate it. I tried out what you said, but for some reason, it still gave me the same error.  Thank you so much though!!

Comment: Yes you are right my solution would not work because Random is a function not a class. You are trying to access the variable allImages from the Random function but the problem is that variables created inside functions only live within that function. So what you would have to do if you want to access this variable from both functions is to take out of the array allImages and List imageList and declare it in the class that wraps those functions. Then your problem should be solved. Let me know if it helps.